# DTO insert null values into database in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

I'm just trying to walk through DTO concept in spring boot app So I create a customer mode, Customer DTO, Customer Service and Controller

But when i test the API through postman, it's insert null values for all attrivbutes, but i don't now why...

and this is the **service** :

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Customer addCustomer(Customer customer) {
    Customer newCustomer = cutomerRepository.save(customer);
    return newCustomer;
}
```

and at last this is the **controller** :

```
public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(CustomerDTO customer) {
    try {
        System.out.println(customer.getEmail()+"000000000000000000000000");
        Customer newCustomer = customerService
                .addCustomer(new Customer(customer.getSerialNumber(), customer.getFirstName(),customer.getLastName(),customer.getEmail(),customer.getMobileNumber()));
        System.out.println(customer.getEmail()+ "************************");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newCustomer, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

the output from 000 and *** are null, and this is how i insert values

Any help or Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@RequestBody` on controller's handler method arg

```
public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(@RequestBody CustomerDTO customer) {
```